# Physical (Quantum Mechanical) Significance of completeness of Hilbert Spaces.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I'm not sure if the question is very 'mathematical',but I'm asking any way. I have a basic knowledge of quantum mechanics and I'm studying Hilbert spaces.

I was wondering what is the physical significance of the `completeness` of a Hilbert Space wrt QM. i.e. why is the completeness required?

How do mathematical properties of Hilbert spaces or Banach spaces play a role in Quantum Mechanics?

Comment: One important point is that you can have a countable orthonormal basis. Otherwise, you are stuck with overcountable Hamel bases.

Comment: Intersting question. I suspect Hilbert spaces are the setting of choice because of mathematical convenience, but I'd like to know more.

Comment: Every non complete space with a inner product is a subspace of a complete one which is it closure, So if you are in a space where all the Cawchy sequence don't converges you may assume that you are in the closure. About the Hilbert basis the pre-Hilbert space has to be separable! Of course I am talking in mathematician view point!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [an MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35840/the-role-of-completeness-in-hilbert-spaces) with some good thoughts on the role of completeness from a mathematical point of view. (I especially like Andrew Stacey's idea of "going to a party hosted by the Square Integrables in their posh mansion, but spending the whole time hanging out with the Schwartz family" :-)

With a view to quantum mechanics, note that the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) (which establishes the bra-ket correspondence) depends on completeness. You can trace the role of completeness in [this proof](https://planetmath.org/ProofOfRieszRepresentationTheorem), which uses the orthogonal decomposition theorem, whose [proof](https://planetmath.org/OrthogonalDecompositionTheorem) in turn uses completeness.

The [history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#History) of the Wikipedia article on Hilbert spaces also has some relevant information.

Answer (score -2):

completeness in hilbert space means that the metric associated with inner product converges,let draw a 1/x as a function on a graph,you will see its area converges to zero.

[image]
as x approaches to infinity 1/x goes to zero